# Creating a table in database defining a column as primary key

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am creating a database from different CSV files. After doing this I have tried to define the primary key table by table but I got an error.

```
c.execute("ALTER TABLE patient_data ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID);").fetchall()

OperationalError: near "PRIMARY": syntax error
```

Maybe the best thing to avoid this error is to define the primary key when the table is create but I dont know how to do that. I have been working with python for a few years but today is my first approach with SQL.

This is the code I use to import a CSV to a table

```
c.execute('''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS patient_data''')
c.execute(''' CREATE TABLE patient_data (ID, NHS_Number,Full_Name,Gender, Birthdate, Ethnicity, Postcode)''')
patients_admitted.to_sql('patient_data', conn, if_exists='append', index = False)
c.execute('''SELECT * FROM patient_data''').fetchall()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.

If your table does not have data, just re-create it with the primary key definition.

If your table does have data, you cannot add a primary key in one statement.  Why not?  The default value is either `NULL` or constant.  And neither is allowed as a primary key.

And finally, SQLite does not allow you to add a primary key to an existing table.  The solution is to copy the data to another table, recreate the table with the structure you want, and then copy the data back in.